# \multicolumn table cell doesn't fit page width

Tags: tables, multicolumn

I have this code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{ |c|c| }
  \hline
  \multicolumn{2}{|c}{\lipsum[1]}\\
  \hline
   text text text text text text & text text text text\\
  \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

It generates this:

[image]

How to make top cell fit the page size, like with X column format?

---

Here is the code, based upon Mico's example. It creates a page-wide table with a column to the left of multicolumn. (The adjustment of `1.2pt` is there to account for the three vertical lines, each `0.4pt` wide, that contribute to the total width of the `tabularx` environment.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum,tabularx,calc,fullpage}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X} % centered version of "X" column type
\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|p{3cm}|Y|Y|}
  \hline
  text text text text text & 
  \multicolumn{2}{p{\dimexpr\textwidth -1.2pt - 4\tabcolsep-3cm}|}{\lipsum[1]}\\
  \hline
  &text text text text text text & text text text text\\
  \hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You don't have  line-breaking with `c`-type columns. Replace `c` by `p{\textwidth}` in the `\multicolumn` command.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use the `tabularx` package and its eponymous `tabularx` environment. The only tricky part is how to get the width of the 2-column term: To calculate the allowable width, you have to subtract from `\textwidth` the following items: `2\tabcolsep`, to account for the whitespace at the left and right hand edges, and `0.8pt` (=2*0.4pt), for the widths of the two vertical lines.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum,tabularx}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X} % centered version of "X" column type
\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|c|Y|}
  \hline
  \multicolumn{2}{|p{\dimexpr\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-0.8pt}|}{\lipsum[2]}\\
  \hline
   text text text text text text & text text text text\\
  \hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

[image]

*Addendum*: If you want the two columns to have equal width (and still have their contents centered), just replace the `c` with a `Y` in the second argument of the `tabularx` specification:

[image]

Comment: How to correctly find the width when we have another column to the left of \multicolumn top cell?

Comment: @user4035 - Please be a bit more specific about the type of columns that might be to the left of the `p` column: Would this be fixed-width column (such as another `p` column), or some other type?

Comment: A fixed width column. I made it work, look at the question edit. But is it possible to get rid of the hard coded values?

Comment: @user4035 - I've edited both your augmented example as well as my own MWE to adjust for the widths of the vertical lines; each such line is `0.4pt` wide...

Comment: eponymous = famous, you mean "homonymous" (= with the same name)

Comment: @yannis - No. Please check with [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/eponymous): "eponymous (adjective): of, relating to, or being the person or thing for whom or which something is named". And, "eponym (noun): one for whom or which something is or is believed to be named". The upshot: My usage of "eponymous" is quite appropriate. In contrast, *homonyms* are words that sound the same but have different meanings; e.g., see/sea, there/their, brake/break, grate/great, etc. I was most definitely not talking about homonyms...

Comment: You are right. I did a search and indeed in ancient Greek (https://el.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E1%BC%90%CF%80%CF%8E%CE%BD%CF%85%CE%BC%CE%BF%CF%82) ἐπώνυμος has five meanings, and #2 is the one you are using, while #5 is the one I was referring to. But in modern Greek (https://el.wiktionary.org/wiki/%CE%B5%CF%80%CF%8E%CE%BD%CF%85%CE%BC%CE%BF%CF%82) it has only meaning #5: "somebody well-known", and this is what caused my error. As for "homonymous" this time you are wrong (https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/homonymous), you are confusing "homonym" and "homonymous", the latter means having the same name.

Comment: @yannis - Thanks. I am more than happy to concede the blindingly obvious, which is that you know Greek infinitely [!!] better than I do. That said, I continue to believe that what I wrote almost 8 years ago, *viz.*, "You could use the `tabularx` package and its eponymous `tabularx` environment", is actually correct. The term "homonymous" refers to things having the same designation or name; in my view, "eponymous" goes farther, "*relating to the thing* for which something is named" [emphasis added]. What I wrote was not meant to observe that "tabularx sounds like tabularx"...